# What is the correct way to say 小さい『つ』?

Tags: kana, spelling

This is a two part question.

1.) When spelling out a word in kana, what is the correct way to call the small つ (for example the small っ in ちっちゃい)?

I only have experience with my Japanese friends using the informal sounding

> 小さい『つ』

or

> ちっちゃい『つ』

Is there a formal grammatical term for this "character"?

2.) If there is, but in reality it sounds too academic, which term would be the most immediately understandable in an informal setting?

Comment: It isn't the name for the character, but I often use 促音{そくおん} to refer to it, since that's what its function is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It appears](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A3) that one more-formal way to describe characters like 「っ」 is to use the phrase 「小書{こが}き」文字{もじ} or simply「小書{こが}き」。  So, in the case of 「っ」, it would be something like: 小書{こが}きの「つ」.

*But in an informal context, something like「小さい『つ』」would probably get the point across.*

For more information, there is [a more detailed writeup](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1163793136) by a user named "nullstrings27" that further explains 小書{こが}き文字{もじ} in general.

Comment: Apparently 捨て仮名 is also an acceptable name as per http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1424710779